Understanding standard error: Is it relevant for a single sample group?
While I do understand standard deviation expresses the deviation from the mean of a population/sample data, not sure how standard error comes into the picture.
Is it true to say that what standard deviation is for sample/population data, standard error is the same for samples of standard deviation of sample groups of a population?
If that so, standard error is non-existent if we have only one sample group? For instance, if I have a traffic data of a website for 10 days, I can find its mean and standard deviation, but no relevance of standard error here?

Very short answer, but answer nonetheless;
The standard error of a statistic is an estimate of the standard deviation of the sampling distribution of that statistic. Just like the mean of the single sample is an estimate of the mean of the sampling distribution of the mean (aka the true mean parameter).
So the standard error is to the sampling distribution, what the standard deviation is to the sample. They are both estimates of the standard deviaton, but of 2 different population; one is the true population, the other is the sampling distribution of a statistic (of a given size $n$) on that population.
The standard error can be defined for any statistic (the mean, the standard deviation, the skewness, etc...). And you can compute it based on just a single sample.
But, as in most (all?) frequentist statistics, the standard error of a statistic is an estimate of the hypothetical standard deviation one would get if one took a very (very, very) large number of hypothetical samples from the same population, and computed the same statistic, and then computed the standard deviation of that statistic.
